# Reading %0 as %0 in CMD

Tags: batch-file, cmd, escaping

I think this is a pretty basic doubt but I could not find the solution myself. What I am trying to do is to create a .bat file in order to automate a data upload process. But the command to be passed in .bat file has to have database password which unfortunately has '%0' in it. So, when I run it, cmd reads it as the file name instead, causing it to run into an error. So, can we write this in a way cmd reads '%0' as it is and doesn't change it to filename?

Comment: Can you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57615936/edit) to include the code you have written which is exhibiting the issue you would like us to help resolve.

Comment: to tell the parser `%` isn't a special character, you have to escape it. The escape character for `%` is another `%`: `echo %%0`

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing your code, it's guessing ...

Probably you are using something like

```
mysql -u root -p secret%0
```

Then you can fix it by doubling the percent sign

```
mysql -u root -p secret%%0
```